# Add tooltip control dynamically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a child form that is completely created in code. 
I would like to add tool tips to the textbox controls on the form. I know how to set up the tool tips on the fly but can't find a way to add the tooltip control to the form on the fly. All the hits I find  on google refer to dragging the control from the designers toolbox.

I would need to do something like:

```
        ' Add tool tip control
        Dim toolTip1 As New ToolTip()
        toolTip1.ShowAlways = True
        frm.Controls.Add(toolTip1)
```

This does not work

I tried adding a sub to handle the from.load event(with a handler that poitn to the sub) at design time but can not get passed the error "Tooltip1 is not declared"  when adding the tooltip to the iundividual dynamic controls.

If I call this dynamic form from a parent form and add the tooltip control to the parent form I can use it for the child form. But how would I do this if I was creating the form from a routine that does not live on a parent form?

thanks

```
        Dim frm As New Form
        ' Add tool tip control
        ''Dim toolTip1 As New ToolTip()
        ''toolTip1.ShowAlways = True
        'Draw the Form object

        'close the dynamic frm if existing already
        If frm IsNot Nothing Then
            frm.Close()
        End If

        frm = New Form()
        frm.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0F, 13.0F)
        frm.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        frm.Name = "frm_test"
        'dimension is irrelevant at the moment
        frm.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(10, 10)
        'the parent will be the current form
        'frm.MdiParent = this;
        'splash screen mode form, why not...
        frm.ControlBox = True
        frm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
        frm.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        frm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
         For Each item As MYFILE.Class in the Collection
         Dim aTextBox As New TextBox()
            aTextBox.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(sFont, Single.Parse(sSizeFont), System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CByte(0))
            aTextBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
            aTextBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(iNewColumnPosition + 5 + intMaxWidthLabel, intVertPos)
            aTextBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(intWidthTextBox + 10, intGapHeight)

            'store the biggest width, so that the textboxes can be vertically aligned
            If intWidthTextBox > intMaxWidthText Then
                intMaxWidthText = intWidthTextBox
            End If

            'giving a name to all your object will be the only way 
            'to retrieve them and use them
            'for the purpose of this sample, the name can be the 
            'same for all textboxes.
            aTextBox.Name = item.ParameterName
            'giving the maximun size in caracters for the textbox.
            aTextBox.MaxLength = Integer.Parse(item.ParameterLength)

            toolTip1.SetToolTip(aTextBox, "TIP" & intIndex.ToString)

            'tab have to be ordered
            aTextBox.TabIndex = intIndex
            intIndex += 1
            'Vertical position is to be manage according the 
            'tallest object in the form, in this case the 
            'textbox it self
            intVertPos += intGapHeight
            'adding the textbox to the form
            frm.SuspendLayout()
            aTextBox.SuspendLayout()
            frm.Controls.Add(aTextBox)
         Next
```

I left a lot of code out but this should give you an idea as to what I am doing

Comment: can you be a little bit more forth coming with the code sample that you are providing..? please show where you are creating the child form I think this may help..we can't tell if `frm` is the `Parent form or Child form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is not in VB.NET but I am pretty sure you can easily convert this.  The first line is to set ToolTip control to your form components.  The second is how you set a tooltip to a control and give it the related text.

```
    ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip(components);
    tooltip.SetToolTip(textBox1, "This is a textbox tooltip");
```

Comment: was Scott's comment in the following reply that answers my question IMO

Answer (score 2):

In vb it is

```
Dim tooltip As New ToolTip(components)
tooltip.SetToolTip(textBox1, "This is a textbox tooltip")
```

Comment: I tried to add the child form (frm) in the components place but this is not right. Dim tooltip As New ToolTip(frm). SO this will not do what I am looking for.

Comment: @DanRowe The ToolTip control would be on each form so you have to have it on each form.  A base form with the ToolTip control would a good start to inherit all your child forms from.  If you don't want to do that, you can pass in a tooltip control to each of your child forms but you are still going to have to have similar code to initialize your tooltip control.  It can only take the components of a form.

Comment: Ok  - so if I created this form from a code module that has no parent form I would not be able to add the tooltip control on the fly?